# Missing maven dependencies in project converted from java to maven

Tags: maven-3

I converted a Java project to maven project. But there are still maven dependencies not in the build path. There maven dependencies do not show up in the lib path.

Comment: When you say "still maven dependencies lib are still not in the build path. " do you mean the eclipse build path ?

Comment: no...Project build path. I am not at all see any maven dependency lib in configure build path of the current project.

Comment: Are you using eclipse, and if yes do you mean the build path of your project in eclipse ?

Comment: Yes using eclipse only.

Comment: You expect a good answer, which takes some effort. Please be so kind and put at least the same effort you are expecting from an answer into asking your question. Otherwise people could get the idea of being treated as a cheap workhorse. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: How do you expect us to know what is issue with your dependencies without looking into your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have converted your project to maven (i.e) you have to do the following in eclipse:

**Right Click on your  and select Maven --> Update Project**

[image]

**This will rebuild your eclipse and all dependencies that is defined in that project pom.xml will be added to your build path under Maven Dependencies.**

[image]

In general all your dependencies will be downloaded to .m2 folder in your system. This will generally be inside your home directory unless you change it in the settings.xml.

Comment: Did you go to your project's build path and check your maven dependencies. Did it get updated. If not post your project structure screen shot  and also your pom.xml

Comment: Also check if you have any maven related problems /errors in "Problems" View, If none then check if the dependencies have been downloaded into your .m2 directory after you run your maven update. Also check if you have mapped your maven installation to your eclipse.